# ambari: mvn clean eclipse:eclipse

Tags: maven, ambari

I am try to run `mvn clean eclipse:eclipse  error` under `ambari` source code as the [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development) said , 
But with error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Ambari Main ........................................ SUCCESS [ 28.207 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.025 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web ......................................... SUCCESS [  5.298 s]
[INFO] Ambari Views ....................................... SUCCESS [  5.082 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View .................................. SUCCESS [03:43 min]
[INFO] ambari-metrics ..................................... SUCCESS [  6.007 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common .............................. SUCCESS [  2.274 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink ......................... SUCCESS [  2.843 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink .......................... SUCCESS [  1.166 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink .......................... SUCCESS [  0.229 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink .......................... SUCCESS [  1.261 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector ........................... FAILURE [ 11.478 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Client ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Shell ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-02T10:33:57+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/141M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-timelineservice:Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-common:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in apache-hadoop (http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea                                                                                        d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso                                                                                        lutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-timelineservice
```

I have no idea how to solve this error,
I tried googling with no answer
Please give me some advice
thanks

Comment: Did you check the link that ambari build process provided when it through the error, it has a few possible solutions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Answer (score 1):

Your Ambari Metrics hasn't be built.
If you plan on installing the Ambari Metrics service, you will also need to build the Ambari Metrics project.

```html
cd ambari-metrics
mvn clean package -Dbuild-rpm -DskipTests
For Ubuntu:
cd ambari-metrics
mvn clean package -Dbuild-deb -DskipTests
```

You can see more in 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development

Answer (score 1):

It is a dependency issue. A maven repository is a directory of packaged JAR files with pom.xml file. Maven searches for dependencies in the repositories. There are 3 types of maven repository:

```
1.Local Repository
2.Central Repository
3.Remote Repository
```

Maven searches for the dependencies in the following order:

**Local repository > Central repository > Remote repository.**

Maven searches the dependency and doesn't find the dependency into local,central and remote.

So first maven build the the ambari. After maven building the project,keep the dependency jar into local repository .

```
mvn clean install
```

It will package the jar and keep it on local repository.

Then you apply

```
mvn clean eclipse:eclipse
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks dude! This is what I was looking for. Worked like charm